# git push heroku master error

Tags: heroku

I'm encountering a problem deploying heroku. The online instructions suggest I follow these steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#deploy-to-heroku

However, when I get to "git push heroku master" I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 12, done. 
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 3.44 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
! Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:mysterious-peak-4781.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mysterious-peak-4781.git'
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: nvm i fixed it, requirements.txt wasnt in the right folder

Answer (score 0):

Rename the app as soon as you create it. It is a must in heroku i guess.

use this command

```
heroku apps:rename NAME
```

**NAME** = what ever name you want to put.

If the above  does not work,

type

```
cd .git
vi config
```

you will get something like this.

```
[remote "heroku"]
url = git@heroku.com:NAME.git
```

This is also a method. Change the name and try.